# How to best convert VARIANT_BOOL to C++ bool?

Tags: c++, windows, com, interop, boolean

When using COM boolean values are to be passed as VARIANT_BOOL which is declared in wtypes.h as *short*. There are also predefined values for *true* and *false*:

```
#define VARIANT_TRUE ((VARIANT_BOOL)-1)
#define VARIANT_FALSE ((VARIANT_BOOL)0)
```

Which is the best way to convert from VARIANT_BOOL to C++ `bool` type? Obvious variants are:

1. compare with VARIANT_FALSE
2. simply cast to bool

Other ways can be easily invented.

Which is the best way to do this - most readable, most standart-compliant, least prone to accidential bugs planting and least prone to issues with porting to 64-bit platforms?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Compare to `VARIANT_FALSE`. There is a lot of buggy code out there that mistakenly passes in the C++ bool `true` value (cast to the integer value 1) to a function expecting `VARIANT_BOOL`. If you compare to `VARIANT_FALSE`, you will still get the correct expected value.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's better to either fix that code, or if you don't control it, to treat it as a special case.

Comment: I rarely have full control over client code. I'd be treating every call as a special case

Answer (score 11):

I don't like to have to worry about compatibility between different boolean values, so I will normally write:

```
VARIANT_BOOL vb_bool = VARIANT_FALSE;

// ... vb_bool set to something by some other code

bool myBool = (vb_bool == VARIANT_TRUE);
```

Are there tinier (as in "will compile to simpler x86 code"), valid ways to do it? Of course. Not worth it. This is guaranteed to work, so I can worry about my business logic.

Answer (score 4):

Casting to bool is obviously wrong.  Some people say (e.g. comments at [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx)) to compare to VARIANT_FALSE, but I would compare to both.  That way you catch invalid values (anything but VARIANT_FALSE or VARIANT_TRUE) early.

e.g.

```
bool VariantBoolToBool(VARIANT_BOOL varFlag)
{
  bool boolFlag;

  switch( varFlag ) 
  {
    case VARIANT_TRUE:
        boolFlag = true;
        break;
    case VARIANT_FALSE:
        boolFlag = false;
        break;
    default:
        throw Exception("Not a valid value");
  }

  return boolFlag;
}
```

Comment: Maybe assert(varFlag == VARIANT_FALSE || varFlag == VARIANT_TRUE)?

Comment: This is worth considering, but I would prefer exceptions in a C++ app.  One reason (besides the other benefits to exceptions) is that I think the check should be in the production code, and assertions tend to wind up disabled.

Comment: Some checks should be done in production code, some in development code. I typically draw the line at what is a programmer error (e.g. passing a null-ptr to a function not accepting it) and external error (e.g. not finding a certain file). In my book conversion functions such as this one are typically more related to programmer errors than to external errors.

Answer (score 3):

Why have an explicit cast?

```
if (my_bool)
{
    blargh();
}
else
{
   blarglerr();
}
```

This way, true is true and false is false, as per the C standard. If you need to SET a C++ style `bool` then do something like:

```
VARIANT_BOOL vb_bool = VARIANT_FALSE
bool cpp_bool = !!vb_bool
```

Comment: Meant to mention the !! - nice!

Answer (score 3):

Declare this macro in one of your global headers.

```
#define b(X) ((X)!=VARIANT_FALSE)
```

EDIT: Much safer version:

```
inline bool b(VARIANT_BOOL v){return v!=VARIANT_FALSE;}
```

Comment: It'd be much safer to have a function for that - the compiler would inline it in release build and it could be stepped into in debug build.

Comment: Hehehe, what about the answer now? :P

Comment: This one is safer, but there's really no point in passing VARIANT_BOOL by reference.

Comment: Yeah, was a mistake, I'm used to dealing with more complex data types and passing it by reference.

Comment: Since you're still keeping the macro in the post you should at least brace it properly: #define b(X) ((X) != VARIANT_FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ conversion rules rely on zero meaning false [and as 1800 INFORMATION points out, the TRUE variant is where the most confusion happens] and nothing more. Hence a static_cast would be best.

But in many cases, the code would be more readable as a comparison. In that case, VARIANT_BOOL is the thing to compare with.